# How to perform flexible serialization of a polymorphic inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: c++, serialization

I have tried to read carefully all the advice given in the [C++FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/serialize-inherit-no-ptrs.html) on this subject. I have implemented my system **according to item 36.8** and now after few months (with a lot of data serialized), I want to make changes in both public interface of some of the classes and the inheritance structure itself.

```
class Base
{
public:
   Vector field1() const;
   Vector field2() const; 
   Vector field3() const;
   std::string name() const {return "Base";}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    std::string name() const {return "Derived";}
};
```

I would like to know how to make changes such as:

1. Split `Derived` into `Derived1` and `Derived2`, while mapping the original `Derived` into `Derived1` for existing data.
2. Split `Base::field1()` into `Base::field1a()` and `Base::field1b()` while mapping `field1` to `field1a` and having `field1b` empty for existing data.

I will have to

1. deserialize all the gigabytes of my old data
2. convert them to the new inheritance structure
3. reserialize them in a new and more flexible way.

I would like to know **how to make the serialization more flexible**, so that when I decide to make some change in the future, I would not be facing conversion hell like now.

I thought of making a system that would use **numbers instead of names** to serialize my objects. That is for example Base = 1, Derived1 = 2, ... and a separate **number-to-name** system that would **convert numbers to names**, so that when I want to change the name of some class, I would do it only in this separate number-to-name system, without changing the data.

The problems with this approach are:

1. The system would be **brittle**. That is changing anything in the number-to-name system would possibly change the meaning of gigabytes of data.
2. The serialized data would lose some of its **human readability**, since in the serialized data, there would be numbers instead of names.

I am sorry for putting so many issues into one question, but I am inexperienced at programming and the problem I am facing seems so overwhelming that I just do not know where to start.

Any general materials, tutorials, idioms or literature on flexible serialization is most welcomed!

Comment: You don't need numbers-to-names or names-to-numbers conversion. You want program entities (types, fields) to (external, serializeable) names mapping. Names given to these entities in the source code are not exactly relevant. You may use source names as default external names, but there should be a possibility to override that.

Comment: The mapping need not be 1:1 either, you may want to write `class NewWidget` as "NewWidget", but read both "Widget" and "NewWidget" as `class NewWidget`. Also, if a field has a sensible default, you just use it when its value is not found in the serialized data. This way you can introduce new fields without much hassle. This will cover maybe 90 per cent of your needs automatically.

Comment: For the other 10 per cent you will need to write conversion code. Just never remove old classes and fields from your code. Write post-deserialization routines for them that will transform them to newer objects.

Comment: I'm a big fan of adding format version numbers to data files (starting with the very first version), so that the software reading them knows what it's dealing with, and can possibly convert as necessary.

Comment: @Loadmaster If I understand correctly, you keep the old data "as is", keep the old deserialization code and apply them on the old data?

Comment: @Loadmaster When it comes to serialization, it's often better to add version numbers to each object, rather than just one for the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a bit late for that now, but whenever designing
a serialization format, you should provide for versionning.
This can be mangled into the type information in the stream, or
treated as a separate (integer) field.  When writing the class
out, you always write the latest version.  When reading, you
have to read both the type and the version before you can
construct; if you're using the static map suggested in the FAQ,
then the key would be:

```
struct DeserializeKey
{
    std::string type;
    int version;
};
```

Given the situation you are in now, the solution is probably to
mangle the version into the type name in a clearly recognizable
way, say something along the lines of
`type_name__version`; if the
`type_name` isn't followed by two underscore,
then use 0.  This isn't the most efficient method, but it's
usually acceptable, and will solve the problem with backwards
compatibility, while providing for evolution in the future.

For your precise questions:

1. In this case, `Derived` is just a previous version of
   `Derived1`.  You can insert the necessary factory function into
   the map under the appropriate key.
2. This is just classical versionning.  Version 0 of `Base` has
   a `field1` attribute, and when you deserialize, you use it to
   initialize `field1a`, and you initialize `field1b` empty.
   Version 2 of `Base` has both.

If you mangle the version into the type name, as I suggest
above, you shouldn't have to convert any existing data.  Long
term, of course, either some of the older versions simply
disappear from your data sets, so that you can remove the
support for them, or your program keeps getting bigger, with
support for lots of older versions.  In practice, I've usually
seen the latter.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) Can help you do it.

Comment: Thank you, but your link seems too advanced for me. I have no idea what they are talking about :(

Comment: @MartinDrozdik It seems more like something that comes a bit too late for you.  (There's also Google protocol blocks.)  Typically, serialization code _is_ generated, not written by hand, and the generator takes care of all of the issues I mention in my answer.  But the probability of your finding a generator which by some miraculous hazard generates exactly the format you use seems fairly small to me.